# Python : Can't delete file after writing

Tags: python, csv

I have a large pipe delimited file I need to split into pieces based on week_number in field 12.  I've written the following script to see if each line matches and if it does write it to another csv file and compress it using gzip.  The problem comes when I try to delete the uncompressed csv file and I get this message:

```
C:\data\weeks_files\week_01.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\python\20150309_laptop_gbm_v1.py", line 45, in <module>
    os.remove(outFileName)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\data\\weeks_files\\week_01.csv'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import re
import gzip
import os

input_file = "C:\\data\\20150226_train_mini.txt"

i_f = open( input_file, 'r' )
reader = csv.reader( i_f , delimiter = '|' )
# reader.next()

for i in range(101,153):

    trainWeek = i
    testWeek = i + 1

    trainPat =  str(trainWeek)[-2:] 
    testPat =  str(testWeek)[-2:] 
    print "trainPat: " , trainPat

    outFileName = "C:\\data\\weeks_files\\week_" + trainPat + ".csv"
    print outFileName

    outFile = open(outFileName, 'wb') 
    mywriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = '|')

# for line in reader:
    for q in range(1,1000):
        line = next(reader)
    # print line
        # print "line[12]:" ,line[12]
        if trainPat in str(line[12]):
            # print "Success!"
            mywriter.writerow(line)
        else:
            line

    # import gzip
    f_in = open(outFileName, 'rb')
    f_out = gzip.open(outFileName+'.gz', 'wb')
    f_out.writelines(f_in)
    f_out.close()
    f_in.close()

    os.remove(outFileName)
```

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: `outFile = open(outFileName, 'wb') ` Where do you close it?

Comment: @u_mulder: ouch, you're right!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As u_mulder hinted you must close a file before deleting it. So add

```
outFile.close()
```

just before your

```
# import gzip
```

comment

Comment: It's idiomatic to use `with` which will automatically close the file at the end of scope.

Comment: Yes my answer aims for minimal changes to answer the question,not re-writing the whole example code so that it is robust, idiomatic, etc. I would likely wrap each commented block in function and add some graceful failures, but the question is not how to clean up the example code.

Comment: Well, there is also the understanding of why the error was made and how to avoid it in future.

Comment: Yes well the best way to avoid bugs is to use an IDE or pylint.

Comment: Following idioms and using built-in language support comes before tools.